# Modifying Calculator in Android Studio

Tags: android

I made a calculator in android studio. It is working fine. But the problem is it is working only for two operands and one operator 2+2. I want to make a calculator as we have on our smartphones. It should do a calculation like 2+2*5/7-8. I tried but I am not able to code this. Can you please help. Here is my code of two operands:

```
TextView zeroTv,oneTv, twoTv,threeTv,fourTv,fiveTv,sixTv,sevenTv,eightTv,nineTv;
TextView addTv,subTv,mulTv,divTv,clearTv,backTv,dotTv,equalTv,percentTv;
TextView exprTv,resultTv;
double firstNo, secondNo;
char operator;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   zeroTv = findViewById(R.id.tvZero_ID);
   oneTv = findViewById(R.id.tvOne_ID);
   twoTv = findViewById(R.id.tvTwo_ID);
   threeTv = findViewById(R.id.tvThree_ID);
   fourTv = findViewById(R.id.tvFour_ID);
   fiveTv = findViewById(R.id.tvFive_ID);
   sixTv = findViewById(R.id.tvSix_ID);
   sevenTv = findViewById(R.id.tvSeven_ID);
   eightTv = findViewById(R.id.tvEight_ID);
   nineTv = findViewById(R.id.tvNine_ID);
   addTv = findViewById(R.id.tvAdd_ID);
   subTv = findViewById(R.id.tvSub_ID);
   mulTv = findViewById(R.id.tvMul_ID);
   divTv = findViewById(R.id.tvDiv_ID);
   clearTv = findViewById(R.id.tvClear_ID);
   backTv = findViewById(R.id.tvBack_ID);
   dotTv = findViewById(R.id.tvDot_ID);
   equalTv = findViewById(R.id.tvEqual_ID);
   percentTv = findViewById(R.id.tvPercent_ID);

   exprTv = findViewById(R.id.tvExpression_ID);
   resultTv = findViewById(R.id.tvResult_ID);

   zeroTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           if (!exprTv.getText().equals(""))
               exprTv.append("0");
       }
   });

   oneTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           exprTv.append("1");
       }
   });

   twoTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           exprTv.append("2");
       }
   });

   threeTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           exprTv.append("3");
       }
   });

   fourTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           exprTv.append("4");
       }
   });

   fiveTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           exprTv.append("5");
       }
   });

   sixTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           exprTv.append("6");
       }
   });

   sevenTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           exprTv.append("7");
       }
   });

   eightTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           exprTv.append("8");
       }
   });

   nineTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           exprTv.append("9");
       }
   });

   dotTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

          exprTv.append(".");
       }
   });

   clearTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           exprTv.setText("");
           esultTv.setText("");
       }
   });

   backTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           String text = exprTv.getText().toString().trim();
           if(text.length() > 0)
           {
               text = text.substring(0,text.length()-1);
               exprTv.setText(text);
            }
       }
   });

   addTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           firstNo = Double.parseDouble(exprTv.getText().toString().trim());
           operator = '+';
           exprTv.setText("");
       }
   });

   subTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           firstNo = Double.parseDouble(exprTv.getText().toString().trim());
           operator = '-';
           exprTv.setText("");
       }
   });

   mulTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           firstNo = Double.parseDouble(exprTv.getText().toString().trim());
           operator = '*';
           exprTv.setText("");
       }
   });

   divTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           firstNo = Double.parseDouble(exprTv.getText().toString().trim());
           operator = '/';
           exprTv.setText("");
       }
   });

   equalTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           secondNo = Double.parseDouble(exprTv.getText().toString().trim());
           double ans;
           switch (operator)
           {
               case '+':
                   ans = firstNo + secondNo;
                   resultTv.setText(""+ans);
                   break;
               case '-':
                   ans = firstNo - secondNo;
                   resultTv.setText(""+ans);
                   break;
               case '*':
                   ans = firstNo * secondNo;
                   resultTv.setText(""+ans);
                   break;
               case '/':
                   ans = firstNo / secondNo;
                   resultTv.setText(""+ans);
                   break;
           }
       }
   });
  }
}
```

Comment: Try with the rule of BODMAS ;)

Comment: if i press any operator after(2+2) the app crashes.

Comment: show your error log

Answer (score 0):

use EXception. you need to put codes inside try ..catch block